# ASP.NET memory problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, windows-server-2003

I have an ASP.NET application that communicates with another API and processes a lot on Page_Load.

If in my browser I hold F5 and hit the site, the server shoots from 120mb to 1.5GB.

I can't find any memory leaks or unclosed objects.  Is there any way or extra things I can do to help?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What happens after you leave your browser for a bit? - does the memory settle back down? Also, what is your CPU utilisation?

Comment: What happens when you release the F5 button, does it recover? And also, there are other ways to performance test your application. Visual studio ultimate has a test suite which you can use to issue a lot of requests and actually have some control over how many requests you perform.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  The code is running inside a usercontrol within a .net cms called Umbraco.  I have taken a look into your questions, it recovers after around 10-15 minutes and goes back down to 45mb and slowly increases to 120mb and stays there.

Problem is, Im finding the site goes down during the weekend because we have around 30-60k visitors.  Is there any way I can decrease memory usage perhaps?

Comment: I use a logging tool called Elmah that I use to catch exceptions.  Could that help if I remove it?  Thanks

Comment: I do get a System.OutOfMemoryException on the weekend and also when I keep the button pressed for a length of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a profiler like [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) or [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).

There are many, many things that could cause that behavior - trying to solve the problem with arbitrary suggestions probably won't get us anywhere.

Once the profiler has identified problem areas, you can post that code in a new question if you aren't able to resolve that problem.

For what it's worth, 1.5 GB isn't *huge*. Does it eventually give an `OutOfMemoryException` if you keep the button pressed?

Comment: YEP! We I do get a System.OutOfMemoryException on the weekend and also when I keep the button pressed for a length of time.

Comment: @Base33 At this point it sounds like a leak. I recommend the profiler to identify problem areas. Things to look for: Interop, instance objects subscribing to static events, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into ANTS Memory Profiler and/or ANTS Performance Profiler from Red Gate. They're very affordable, and they do a great job of identifying bottlenecks.

ANTS Memory Profiler:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

ANTS Performance Profiler:
http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/

Answer (score 0):

+1 to "profile and figure out problems" - knowing what is happening is must if you want to solve the issue.

But in short term it may be cheaper and easier to move to decent 64 bit box/64 bit version of Windows and use 64 bit ASP.Net - you'll get much more memory available to IIS process.